# How to install 'MySQL Utilities' using brew or brew cask?

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, mysql

I installed MySQL server and client using `brew`. I installed MySQL Workbench with `brew cask`, but I don't find [MySQL Utilities](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/utilities/) (something new?).

How to install that using `brew` or `brew cask`?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: https://github.com/dbcli/mycli
this is good idea, A Terminal Client for MySQL with AutoCompletion and Syntax Highlighting. It is great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mysql-utils is a different cask

```
brew cask install mysql-utilities
```

if you do a `brew search mysql` you can see the caskroom casks

```
$ brew search mysql
automysqlbackup
mysql ✔
mysql++
mysql-cluster
mysql-connector-c
mysql-connector-c++
mysql-sandbox
mysql-search-replace
mysqltuner              
homebrew/php/php53-mysqlnd_ms
homebrew/php/php55-mysqlnd_ms
homebrew/versions/mysql51
homebrew/versions/mysql56
Caskroom/cask/mysqlworkbench                 
homebrew/php/php54-mysqlnd_ms
homebrew/php/php56-mysqlnd_ms
homebrew/versions/mysql55
Caskroom/cask/mysql-utilities    <<<<=============
Caskroom/cask/navicat-for-mysql
```

In order to have a functional mysql-utils you would need to have the python connector. You can download it from

```
 http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/  (osX 10.8 and 10.9)
 or 
 https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/2.0.html (osX 10.7)
```

But I prefer to have from the .tar.gz and install it manually. You can have detailed instructions [here](http://pablomarin-garcia.blogspot.com.es/2016/01/installing-mysqlworkbench-and-mysql.html)

Answer (score 10):

This will do it:

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew install brew-cask
brew cask install mysqlworkbench
```

Comment: I need "MySQL Utilities" not Workbench.

Comment: how do i install version 5.6